Neural Network - catenate layer with an input in the form of <|"x"->{"y","z"}|>
I'm doing a research project that requires me to make a custom neural network, and one major challenge I'm facing is that a few pieces of the input data can have varying dimensionality. Specifically, I want to run an encoder on an array of inputs (it seems) and return just one output. So, for example, let's say I had the data
<|"Subjects_1"-> {"Math","English"},"Subjects_2"-> {"Math"}|>.
Suppose this means that student 1 is taking Math and English, while student 2 is only taking Math. How can I input this kind of data into a Neural Network layer (like maybe CatenateLayer[]) through an encoder (like maybe NetEncoder[ {"Class, {"Math", "English"}, "IndicatorVector"}]? I was considering alternatively using a NetEncoder[ {"Function", ...}] for this, but I'm also not sure how to go about that.
I would like to be able to connect this with a LinearLayer[] or something, but I'm just really struggling at the moment with reshaping the data to, regardless of input size, take on a set output form. I've tried using ResizeLayer[] and ReshapeLayer[] but haven't made much headway with those either. Any and all help would be incredibly appreciated! I'm running really behind schedule with this project and this is the last major hurdle I have to face.
Maybe something with ConvolutionLayer[] or FlattenLayer[] or even PoolingLayer[] would be good for this, but again, I'm really lost. I'm not a comp sci expert at all and Mathematica is really pushing me to my limits haha.
I think the big issue is that for some reason Mathematica is evaluating each element of the KeyValue as a different process instead of joining them together, so that's throwing off my NetGraph[]. So, going back to the students example, I would often get the output {{1,0},{0,1}} for {"Math","English"} (interpreted as two results) rather than what I would want, which is {1,1} (adding the two "results" together). Again, so that regardless of the amount of inputs, the layer outputs a fixed-dimension vector.

Why not just one hot encode your inputs?

Would I be able to one hot encode with multiple inputs? Like two hot? I'm not sure... either way one hot encoding that accounts for all the permutations isn't feasible for this encoder :/

You can encode a finite list of subjects using one hot encoding, <|"Subjects_1"-> {"Math","English"},"Subjects_2"-> {"Math"}|> will transform into <|"Subjects_1"-> {1, 1},"Subjects_2"-> {1, 0}|> and {"English"} into {0, 1}. I don't see how permutations are relevant here. But you could do something like: {{E}, {M}, {E, M}, {M, E}} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
